# Apply different text headings to html <hr> element with the same class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the `<hr>` tag to style and include different headings for parts of my website.  I am using CSS pseudo elements to add the heading text to the `<hr>` element.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="steps">
    <div id="step1"><hr class="stepheading">contentcontent</div>
    <div id="step2"><hr class="stepheading">contentcontent</div>
    <div id="step3"><hr class="stepheading">contentcontent</div>
    <div id="step4"><hr class="stepheading">contentcontent</div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
hr.stepheading{
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: medium double #333;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    margin: 130px 0px;
}

hr.stepheading:after{
    content: "The First Step";
    position: relative;
    top: -0.7em;
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}
```

So, I can see that the problem is that every single one of my headings will contain "The First Step" instead of other headings for other steps.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQBgL/16/)

I want each heading to have a different title: "The First Step," "The Second Step," etc...

How do I go about doing that and what technology do I use?  Can this be done in purely HTML and CSS or do I have to use Javascript/JQuery to achieve what I want?

Comment: You could use a different class for each text, but why are you adding content this way? It's not good practice. Also why not use heading tags such as `h1`, `h2`, etc.?

Comment: "I am trying to use the <hr> tag to style and include different headings for parts of my website" sounds like you are using the wrong tag for the job.  Headlines should be marked up using the headline tags (h1-h6).  Borders can be styled to appear similar to an `hr` element.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm trying to achieve something like this for headings: http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/  Basically, using `<hr>` for a more stylized heading look.

Comment: But the only thing you're really using the `hr` for is the double border, which can be achieved by styling the `h1`s top border:  http://jsfiddle.net/bQBgL/17/.  CSS is for styling only, the document still needs to make sense when you take away all styling.

Comment: I see.  I suppose I can use heading tags `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nth-child()` on the `div` element:

```
hr.stepheading:after{
    content: "The First Step";
    position: relative;
    top: -0.7em;
    display: inline-block; 
    /* Other details */
}

div:nth-child(2) hr.stepheading:after{
    content: "The Second Step";
}
div:nth-child(3) hr.stepheading:after{
    content: "The Third Step";
}
div:nth-child(4) hr.stepheading:after{
    content: "The Fourth Step";
}​
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQBgL/4/

Comment: There is little point using nth-child when ID's are readily available

Answer (score 0):

```css
#step2 hr.stepheading:after { content: "The Second Step"; }​
#step3 hr.stepheading:after { content: "The Third Step"; }​
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gLQ37/

HTML:

```
<div id="steps">
 <div id="step1"><h1 class="stepheading"id="hr1"></h1>contentcontent</div>
 <div id="step2"><h1 class="stepheading" id="hr2"></h1>contentcontent</div>
 <div id="step3"><h1 class="stepheading" id="hr3"></h1>contentcontent</div>
 <div id="step4"><h1 class="stepheading" id="hr4"></h1>contentcontent</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
h1.stepheading{
padding: 0;
border: none;
border-top: medium double #333;
text-align: center;
color: #333;
margin: 130px 0px;
}

h1.stepheading:after{
position: relative;
top: -0.7em;
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0 0.25em;
background: white;
}

#hr1:after{content: "The First Step";}
#hr2:after{content: "The Second Step";}
#hr3:after{content: "The Third Step";}
#hr4:after{content: "The Fourth Step";}​
```